# Why do I get inconsistencies in this method when running

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

Sometimes the varible total will equal something else when run instead of 50005000 it's allways short like 50005001 when sometimes run why is this happening shouldn't synchronized(this) create a lock which can only be updated once the lock is released by the thread?

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public class CurrentThread {
    public static AtomicLong c = new AtomicLong(0L);
    public static AtomicLong total = new AtomicLong(0L);
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
        System.out.println(t);
        t.setName("My Thread");
        System.out.println(t);

        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            System.out.println("Instance " + x);
            new Thread(new Updater(x, "Thread: " + String.valueOf(x))).start();
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }    
    }
}
class Updater implements Runnable {
    public int na;   
    private String threadName;  
    public Updater(int n, String threadName) {
        this.na = n;
        this.threadName = threadName;  
    }  
    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.updateCount();
        if(CurrentThread.total.get() == 50005000) {
            System.out.println("Passed");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Failed");
        }
    }    
    public  void  updateCount() {

            while (CurrentThread.c.get() < 10000) {
                synchronized(this) {
                    CurrentThread.c.getAndIncrement();
                    CurrentThread.total.addAndGet(CurrentThread.c.get());
                    System.out.println(this.threadName + " " + String.valueOf(CurrentThread.c.get()) + " " + CurrentThread.total.get() + " " + System.nanoTime());
                }
            }
      }  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're synchronizing on `this`, which is effectively not synchronizing at all, since each thread has a different `Runnable` instance.

Synchronize on something shared between all `Updater` instances instead, e.g. `Updater.class`.

---

Note, however, that synchronizing on `AtomicLong` is a bit of a code smell - it's meant to do things atomically already.

You can use `compareAndSet` instead, and avoid synchronizing entirely, e.g.:

```
while (CurrentThread.c.get() < 10000) {
  while (true) {
    long currValue = CurrentThread.c.get();
    if (currValue >= 10000) break;

    long newValue = currValue + 1;

    // Only sets c to newValue if its value is still currValue.
    if (CurrentThread.c.compareAndSet(currValue, newValue)) {
      long total = CurrentThread.total.addAndGet(newValue);
      System.out.println(
          this.threadName + " " + newValue + " " + total + " " + System.nanoTime());
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this makes use of "known" values, like `newValue` and `total`, rather than getting them again from the `AtomicLong`.

Comment: Where would the correct place be to use the synchronized modifier? Currently working through the book Java Concurrency in Practice.

Comment: That is an incredibly broad question - wherever you need to perform multiple actions atomically, and mutually exclusively with respect to other threads. The point is that you don't need it here because `AtomicLong` provides an alternative (and lighter-weight) method.

Comment: You don't need any synchronization here because your shared `public static AtomicLong total` provides atomic operations. (I haven't used `AtomicLong` but it should be behaving the way as named)

Comment: I think there is a race condition in the code somewhere as I am using two AtomicLong objects. @sura2k

Comment: @sura2k simply using `AtomicLong` doesn't guarantee atomic updates - not least because there are updates between two instances of `AtomicLong`. You can do it atomically - as demonstrated above - you just have to be very careful.

Comment: @AndyTurner is it possible a race condition is happening somewhere at the start of the creation of Updater instances? Since the value is always off by a like 1,2,3,4,5 never more

Comment: @Andy - My bad, I just saw one. What happens if the first thread goes idle just after the `if (CurrentThread.c.compareAndSet(currValue, newValue)) {` and 2nd thread does both the `c.compareAndSet` and `total.addAndGet` at once , then the thread 1 comes back and executes `total.addAndGet` ? Would the be fine?

Comment: @sura2k I suppose you're right. See, this is what I mean about you having to be very careful.